# How can I trace which user account my kids dead phone had?

Tags: google-account, data-recovery, fastboot

My kid broke his phone. (Well actually, a bully classmate broke it..) It's all black, but probably runs. Not-rooted.

Problem: I've forgot his gmail-account. Can I grab the used account (not password) through adb or fastboot somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Is [usb-debugging](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-debugging/info) enabled at all? Then you definitely can. That's one of the things my little tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) does:

```
adb shell dumpsys account
```

gives you all the account information (which accounts exist on the device), including the Google one. No root required.